# Calculate memory address with Pointer & Offset

Tags: autoit

I'm doing inventory automation for the store I work for.
I need to read an address and know the quantity of items sold in the week.

I was able to find the BaseAddress and Offset:
0x0ac22c78 0x380

I'm using an autoit code to read.

But it only read the generated address, not read using the BaseAddress.

How can I find the generated address?
The code is:

> Can be in C # or C ++
>   I just want to locate the generated address.

```html
Local $iPid = WinGetProcess("Store")
Local $iAddress = 0x0AFDE298

If $iPid = -1 Then
    ConsoleWrite("+++ Failed to get process PID. Open good process or change parameter in WinGetProcess func." & @CRLF)
    Exit
EndIf

Local $hHandle = DllCall("kernel32.dll", 'int', 'OpenProcess', 'int', 0x1F0FFF, 'int', 1, 'int', $iPid)

If @error Then
    ConsoleWrite("+++ Failed to open process memory for FULL_ACCESS. Error is " & @error & @CRLF)
    Exit
EndIf

Local $tagStruct = "struct;double var1;endstruct"

Local $sStruct = DllStructCreate($tagStruct)

If @error Then
    ConsoleWrite("+++ Failed to create $sStruct. Error is " & @error & @CRLF)
    Exit
EndIf

DllCall("kernel32.dll", 'int', 'ReadProcessMemory', 'int', $hHandle[0], 'int', $iAddress, 'ptr', DllStructGetPtr($sStruct), 'int', DllStructGetSize($sStruct), 'int', '')

If @error Then
    ConsoleWrite("+++ Failed to Read Process Memory. Error is " & @error & @CRLF)
    Exit
EndIf

Local $vRet = DllStructGetData($sStruct, "var1")

If @error Then
    ConsoleWrite("+++ Failed to Get data from $sStruct. Error is " & @error & @CRLF)
    Exit
EndIf

ConsoleWrite("++ Successfully read memory at addr 0x" & Hex($iAddress) & " value is " & $vRet & @CRLF)
```

Comment: It's unclear how getting the memory address of a struct in memory will do what you want. You should clarify your problem and maybe supply an example of business logic that does what you need.

Comment: We use a program called "Store" to make sales.
I want to read his memory, pick up the number of single items sold to do a stock control.

Using the CheatEngine tool I was able to locate the address. The script read perfectly. But every time you turn on the PC the addres changes.
So I want to adapt to read the BaseAddress and Offset.

Comment: You should [edit] the question and put these details in there. This might be a bit of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). It sounds like you are intercepting data from a running binary, and you want to be able to do that reliably on subsequent runs. Tell us if this is case, and explain how you are doing things, including sharing whatever tools and APIs you are using. Your code example should illustrate the problem, and you should show example output that shows your problem.

Comment: That all being said, the whole point of modern linkers and randomized stacks is to make it hard to guess where some specific runtime data happens to be, or to know anything about its overall size and structure on the stack or heap. So you should _really_ concentrate on showing us how you think your toolset can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're not finding an address, you're finding a pointer to an address.

How to solve it's really easy...

**Option 1:**

- Check function calls (right click address -> check what writes to this address).

**Option 2:**

- PointerScan (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQ2F2iW80Fk)

**Option 3: NOT RECOMMENDED**

- Bruteforcing offsets.

**How to read memory with Autoit:**

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/55095-how-can-read-value-from-memory-address/

**How to read values from a pointer**

Read the pointer value -> point to value as a new address -> result